# How to reder page only after await function

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

[image]I have the following code ..

```
const WalletScreen = () => {

  const checkBalance = async () => {
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    let tempBalance;
    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      const notFirstRun = docSnap.data().notFirstRun;
      if (notFirstRun) {
        Wbalance = docSnap.data().WalletBalance;
      } else {
        tempBalance = 1000000;
        await setDoc( docRef,
          { WalletBalance: tempBalance, notFirstRun: true },
          { merge: true }
        ).catch((error) => {
          alert(error.message);
        });
      }
    }
    return tempBalance;
  };
  let displayBalance = checkBalance();

 return (
   <View style={{ backgroundColor: "white", alignItems: "center" }}>
     <Text style={{ fontSize: 42, marginVertical: 30 }}>
       K{(displayBalance / 100)}
     </Text>
   </View>
 );
```

};

I have a function checkBalance where I am trying to show an amount on the screen. If it is the first run of the app, the balance(stored in tempBalance) is set to 1000000 and saved in the firestore database, if it isn't the first run however, the balance should be retrieved from Firestore. At the end there is variable displayBalance that is to be used to display the balance. I thought using async await will mean all this will happen before the page is rendered, however it displays NAN like in the photo attached. Could anyone point out where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem comes from your await syntax not affecting the scope containing the part you want to stall. To solve this with react mentality, I use the `useEffect` hook, and have a function which runs once on the initial load, and change a loading state to determine what to render. This idea, of having different states render depending on the content recieved from a database or some function execution could be repurposed for your use case. Hopefully this helps shed some light on solving your problem!

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const AfterAsync = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    useEffect(() => {
      const wait = new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
      wait.then(() => setIsLoading(false));
    }, []);
    
    if (isLoading) return (
      <div> Loading </div>
    );
    return (
        <div> finished loading! </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <AfterAsync />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the comment. It should me the importance of using the useState hook in assigning a value to the variable outside of the function and is what I used as part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I realise the first mistake I was making above was, when it isn't the first run I was assigning the value to a different variable (Wbalance) than the one I was supposed to use (tempbalance).

```
if (notFirstRun) {
    Wbalance = docSnap.data().WalletBalance;
}
```

Secondly, using the useState hook to define the variable and assign it a value is what works. It still displays "NaN" on page load but when the data is ready from firebase, it reloads and displays the value. Also I am not sure if it is okay assigning a value to a variable declared outside the function as this makes it checkBalance an impure function but it is the solution that gives me the desired functionality for now. My final code is below:

```
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { doc, getDoc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { auth, db } from "../resources/firebase";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const WalletScreen = () => {
  //Create state variable
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState();

  //Create a function that fetches the balance from firebase.
  //Fist check if the user is signed in
  const checkBalance = (auth, db) => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        let tempBalance;
        const docRef = doc(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid);
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef).catch((error) =>
          alert(error.message)
        );
        if (docSnap.exists()) {
          const notFirstRun = docSnap.data().notFirstRun;
          if (notFirstRun) {
            tempBalance = docSnap.data().WalletBalance;
            setBalance(tempBalance);
          } else {
            tempBalance = 1000000;
            await setDoc(
              docRef,
              { WalletBalance: tempBalance, notFirstRun: true },
              { merge: true }
            ).catch((error) => {
              alert(error.message);
            });
            setBalance(tempBalance);
          }
        }
      } else {
        return; //If the user isn't signed in, simply return
      }
    });
  };

  checkBalance(auth, db);

  return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: "white", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 42, marginVertical: 30 }}>
        K{(balance / 100)}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```